# How can you get the schema of a column in KQL?

Tags: kql

I use this syntax to get the schema from a table :
{Name of table}
| getschema

But what is the syntax for getting the schema of a column ?
For exemple getting the schema of the column "ActionType" from the table DeviceEvents.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to get the schema of a single column? How to get the schema of a dynamic (json) column?

Comment: @Heartcore - did the answer below help? If yes, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If you still need more info, please add a comment, elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "column schema". But I guess you want to get the table's schema, and then filter by the column name, to see its type etc. If so, this is how you do it:

```
TableName
| getschema 
| where ColumnName == "ColumnName"
```

If, on the other hand, you have a dynamic column, and you'd like to understand its structure, then you can do the following:

```
TableName
| where ingestion_time() > ago(5m)
| summarize buildschema(RequestObject)
| mv-expand schema_Payload = treepath(schema_RequestObject)
| project schema_Payload
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers sir !
But actually I was looking for this :





 {Table} 
 | distinct {Column} -> Gives you all the distinct data types of a column.

Comment: But a column always has just one datatype. Or do you mean that you want to know which datatypes there are in the table? In this case, use `TableName | getschema | distinct ColumnType`.